# Authorize.net error in magento2

Tags: magento2, authorize.net

I am getting following error in my authorize.net. Is this of  `HTTPS` problem or something else?

please check the error below:

> The reporting of this
>   transaction to the Merchant has timed out. An e-mail has been sent to
>   the merchant informing them of the error. The following is the result
>   of the attempt to charge your credit card.
>   
>       This transaction has been
>   approved.
>
> It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to
>   verify that you will receive the product or
>   service.

Comment: Please give this answer if any one know.

Comment: @PayalPatel  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10293 refer this

Comment: @JeevaChezhiyan have found solution